# package relocation/rename using Maven dependency?

Tags: java, scala, maven, dependency-management, maven-shade-plugin

Package relocation/rename is a major solution for jar hell issue. But one problem that troubles me for long time is that such solution are not effective on running in IDE directly or executing maven-test, so they will still suffer from Jar hell.

I'm looking for a maven plugin that can handle this on dependency level: so I can manually configured to rename package and rewrite classloading of them. Is it possible in Java and any built tool?

Comment: You are talking about the java package name/structure ? If you change the package names/structure you need to install your changes artifact and from there you can use it...Can explain more in detail what your problem is?

Comment: I'm not going to manually change and mvn install the as its quite onerous. I need a maven plugin that can apply this to specific dependencies for me. maven-shade can do this in packaging (in particular, packaging of fat/uber jar) but won't be helpful for all other cases. I'm simply looking for a plugin that extend this feature for all stages (compiling/test/packaging)